# Bootstrap form grid flow help block size issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, validation, grid

I have a form with the columns flowing from row to row. When the help block is added during a validation, the height of a column element gets larger causing the flow to be off.

Not sure what to do to prevent the bump to the next column.

[image]

```
.
```

Here is a fiddle with what is basically happening.
http://jsfiddle.net/pkoh2vuj

Comment: You should post a working example of the problem.

Comment: @vanburenx here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pkoh2vuj It shows the basic behavior that I am getting. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I must be missing something because I don't understand the issue via the jsfiddle.

Comment: @vanburenx It looks like the last changes in the fiddle. This one should be better.
http://jsfiddle.net/pkoh2vuj/4/

Comment: Are you using a validation library though?

Comment: I am using parsley to add the validations. 
I went ahead and copied the relevant parts into an updated fiddle. (http://jsfiddle.net/pkoh2vuj/6/)

When there is a validation error, I have it use the bootstrap validation state. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

Comment: Is the issue the submit button moving or a whole input being pushed to one side when the validation errors are present? If you aren't dead set on using Parsley I would take a look at jQuery Validate just as a suggestion.